# How to do command-line completion with files and folders

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete

As a new Linux user, one of the things that's kept me away from the Command Line (CL) is that, for tasks involving files and folders (i.e. everything!), the amount of typing involved makes using the CL inefficient. I myself have a tendency to use detailed file names. For example, if I have a book called "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems", which is in its 9th edition and is written by William Boyce and Richard DiPrima, then I'll name it like:

`elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems_9ed_boyce_diprima.pdf`.

So in my effort for learning to use the CL I've look around for ways to overcome this problem and found about [*Command-line completion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) with the `Tab` key. The thing with this is that it does word completion but only for commands, not for files and folders. I would like to know if there is a similar feature that works for files?

Comment: What shell are you using? All that I can think of that have tab completion at all support it for filenames in argument position in general.

Comment: The standard one, I think. I just downloaded Xterm and have used that since. But, how do you do tab completion for files? Could you elaborate please.

Comment: Type, say, `xpdf elem` and press Tab. Bash, which I guess is what you mean by "standard" shell will (by default) complete that name.

Comment: What distribution are you using? Then we can sort out what your default shell is.

Comment: I use Fedora 20.

Comment: You're using bash if it's F20. xterm is the terminal emulator, if you're using stock F20 then it's likely `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: As michael has stated, if you keep hitting the tab key *after* the name of a command which can operate against a file type, such as `xpdf`, the Bash shell will complete the names of files there as you repeatedly hit the tab key.

Answer (score 2):

I use `bash`, and on `tab`, the file name completion happens as well.

But for the specific example that you have taken - of long file names, if you have many files with the same prefix in the directory, *many* `tab`s would be needed to get to the file!

I faced a similar problem with one codebase which I was working with, and the workaround I created for myself was, to have an `alias` + Perl script combination, to which I would give only the first letters, of the *words* in file name. E.g,

```
$ ls
elementary_differentail_equations.pdf # 1
elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems.pdf # 2
elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems_9ed_boyce_diprima.pdf # 3

$ opdf e d e                      # opens 1
$ opdf e d e a b v p              # opens 2
$ opdf e d e a b v p 9 b d        # opens 3
```

where `opdf` is the alias (say), which only looks for `.pdf` extension.

Comment: Can you post a link to the script?

Comment: @muru, its here, its a perl script, plus you have to setup your environment to use it, as in, aliases etc. https://github.com/aniruddha-a/short_open

Comment: Thanks. I think `zsh` has a similar feature, but I'm too lazy to switch shells.

Answer (score 2):

When using Bash and its ability to perform completion via the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, there are 2 aspects to the completion that might be getting confused.

When you type a letter at the prompt and start hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll notice the behavior you're describing.

#### Example

> $ el<kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
el4-rpmlint  el5-rpmlint  elbadmin     elfedit      elif    elinks    else
```

This is searching your system's `$PATH` and presenting executables that match your search criteria, i.e. `el`.

However if you have a directory of files such as this one below, you can use the same completion capabilities via <kbd>Tab</kbd> like so.

Sample files:

```
$ ls -1
efile.pdf
elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems_9ed_boyce_diprima.pdf
elements1.pdf
```

#### Example

Performing this:

> $ ls el<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Bash would autocomplete this up to the word `element`. At which point it would stop since that's the largest string that is common among a group of files (or a single file) within the current directory. If you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice now, Bash will list out the files that matched up to this point:

> $ ls element<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems_9ed_boyce_diprima.pdf
>       elements1.pdf
>
> $ ls element

It will then bring you back to your same location in your prompt. Bash basically did a `ls element*` for you in that moment. If you type a letter or two to help guide Bash on which file you want from the subset it presented you and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it will attempt to match some more of your files with your extended string you now have at the prompt:

> $ ls elementa<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Would be enough to get you the rest of your filename:

> $ ls elementary_differentail_equations_and_boundary_value_problems_9ed_boyce_diprima.pdf

Answer (score 0):

*An alternative approach for the details of your question about what you are really trying to achieve:  less typing.*

You may also find that good aliases let you have the best of both worlds, i.e. long folder names.  I like long folder names and I also like short names for typing and I achieve this with aliases such as:

```
alias zab='cd ~/mycar/activerecord-boolean-converter'
alias q='cd ~/Dropbox/95_2014/work/code/ruby__rails/ruby/ruby_quiz'
alias dummy='cd ~/zipcar/zipcar-rails-core/spec/dummy'
```

Then I just type, for example, <kbd>q</kbd> then press <kbd>return</kbd>